# Covariant formulation of electrodynamics

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, terminology, tensor-calculus, covariance

IMO 'covariant formulation' of electrodynamics means that the equations should remain invariant across different Lorentz frames. Now there are broadly two ways to write electrodynamics equations.

1. using 3 vector notation
   $$
   \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} + \nabla.\mathbf{J} = 0 \tag{Eq. 11.127 of J.D.Jackson} 
   $$
2. using 4 vector notation and tensors
   $$
   \partial_\alpha J^\alpha = 0 \tag{Eq. 11.129 of J.D.Jackson}
   $$

An electrodynamics equation written in either of these two ways remains invariant (form-wise) across all Lorentz frames. Then why is it that the latter is referred to as the 'covariant formulation' but not the former?

Comment: This is semantics but the last one is sometimes referred to as "explicitly covariant".  Also technically as written it is "invariant" rather than covariant since the rhs is a scalar.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Invariant is a special case of covariant; it's perfectly fine to call it covariant.

Comment: There's also the (equivalent) differential forms approach, where the above would be written as $d\star\mathbf{J}  = 0$.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's true that the first equation has the same form in all Lorentz frames, but it's not obvious unless you know how $\rho$ and ${\bf J}$ individually transform.  For example, the similar-looking equation

$$ \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} + k\, {\bf \nabla} \cdot {{\bf E}} = 0$$

(where $k$ is some constant) would *not* look the same in other Lorentz frames, because charge density and electric field transform differently under Lorentz boosts.  The second equation, on the other hand, is *clearly* Lorentz-covariant, because any contraction between a covariant and contravariant index of a Lorentz tensor is automatically covariant (i.e. that contraction has the same algebraic form in any other Lorentz frame).